# Weird behaviour of EditText with TextWatcher

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I don't know if this is a bug or I am missing something, but it looks like the former. 
I have an `EditText` to which I have added a `TextWatcher` as follows:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

and the `TextWatcher` has been implemented this way:

```
private final TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        Log.d(TAG, "before editing");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String text = s.toString();
        if(text.length() < 2) {
            if(listView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return;
        }

        showSuggestions(text);
    }
};
```

Now, the weird part is that if I remove the `Log` in the `beforeTextChanged` method, the `afterTextChanged` method is never called, and the `EditText` does not show the new input. On the other hand, whatever line of code I put in that method makes it work fine. Explanation?

Comment: `afterTextChanged` is supposed to be called regardless of `beforeTextChanged`, I suspect that the problem is elsewhere in your code.. have you tried logging `afterTextChanged` to see if its called or not ?

Comment: Yes, and it's not called

Comment: I created a new project with one `EditText`, added a `TextWatcher` and logging to `afterTextChanged` and its being called...